invalid_appid in agora acquire api in call recording
Trying to implement a video calling system using agora android sdk.
Have created my account and enable the cloud recording. In the documentation it's mentioned that to start the video calling we need to call the /cloud_recording/acquire this api first to get the resourceId. I have added the authorization customerid and password properly but when calling the api in the response I am getting 400 error as invalid_appid but I have just copy and paste the app id from console .
{
"cname": "usercreatedchannel",
"uid": "154",
"resourceId": "",
"code": 400,
"reason": "invalid_appid"
}
getting this in the response , how can I solve this?

I had exact same issue and enabled cloud recording and it resolved the issue.
